# Как использовать PropertyConfigurator в новой версии log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j

Сейчас я использую **slf4j-log4j12 1.7.30**.
При которой используется такая строка

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
```

Хочу обновить на

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

но при обновлении подключается все, кроме `PropertyConfigurator`.
Как подключить `log4j.properties`??